# using static variable in xcode

Tags: objective-c, static

In my project , I have a search bar .

if the text in the search bar changed , I need to know

so I declare two static NSMutableString to compare as following

```
static NSMutableString *latestKeyWord;
static NSMutableString *secondaryKeyWord;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [testViewController setSecondaryKeyWord:SBar.text];
    [testViewController setLatestKeyWord:SBar.text];
    [testViewController changeKeyWord];
}
    +(void)setSecondaryKeyWord:(NSMutableString*) text
{
    if (!secondaryKeyWord) {
        secondaryKeyWord = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:200];
    }
    [secondaryKeyWord setString:text];
}

+(void)setLatestKeyWord:(NSMutableString*)text
{
    if (!latestKeyWord) {
        latestKeyWord = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:200];
    }
    [latestKeyWord setString:secondaryKeyWord];
}

-(BOOL)changeKeyWord
{
    if ( ! [latestKeyWord isEqualToString:secondaryKeyWord]) {
         NSLog(@"changed");
        return TRUE;
    }else {
        NSLog(@"not change");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

it just stocked and I have no idea why.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you using static variables and not instance variables? And why `NSMutableString` and not a simple `NSString`?

Comment: I am parsing a website.
I have another static NSInteger named pageNumber and another function named startParsing.
When I call starParsing the first time,it would parse page 1,
the second time parse page 2 etc..
so pageNumber is remember which page I need to parse next.
If the text in SearchBar changed the pageNumber need to reset (`pageNum = 0`)
I declare two `NSMutableString` to compare .
I use `NSMutableString` is because static variable only use the method which have prefix '+' and I didn't find the method can initial with capasity in NSString .
Thanks for your response!

Comment: So you want to be notified when the text changes in your text field?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when the text in a text field changes you add a target/action to the text field:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *field;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *searchText;
@end


@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 25);
    self.field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.field addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:self.field];
}

- (void)textChanged:(id)sender {
    self.searchText = self.field.text;
    NSLog(@"Text changed to: %@", self.searchText);
    // restart searching here.
}
@end
```

Comment: it works!thanks!! but i got a little confused with the first parameter in `[self.field addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];`..in my opinion, it would always be `self`